# Synthesizable delayed buffer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, counter

I am trying to generate a synthesizable buffer in VHDL for a time-to digital project in FPGA.
I have been looking around but cannot find any set-up out there.
I have been recommended that stackoverflow has very good answers.
Could you please give me some tips for this course work, and I would be very greatful to any approach you might come up with.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Regards

Comment: For synthesizable multi-cycle delays, you typically just feed your samples into a shift register. If you need a really long/wide delay line and don't need parallel access, you can also use a BRAM FIFO to save resources. You'll need to give us more specific details about the problem for anybody to give you an answer much more specific than that.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, what I am trying to do is a time to digital converter where a buffer is need with the minimum possible delay  where the signal is tapped by a latch.  [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-to-digital_converter) I have already modeled a one bit counter where the delay is the internal clock frequency of the ILO.

Answer (score 1):

Doing time-delay-circuits (TDC) is somewhat *hard* right now.

Basically, it boils down to having HDL that describes multiple registers all reading the same signal. You then need to apply a *keep* directive, e.g. *equivalent_register_removal* for Xilinx. You will possibly also need a timing ignore constraint on the signal you are sampling.

You then need to carefully examine the fabric of your FPGA and make sure your flop flops are placed in the same slice across multiple sites that can all be connected through the same kind of wire (check FPGA Editor), i.e. will have the same time delay.

You can build a minimal test design for Xilinx in FPGA editor. Once you have the routing down, you can then formulate appropriate constraints for your UCF file and build much bigger, more complex TDCs.

I'm only familiar with Altera from a few years ago. But Altera doesn't give you an interface like Xilinx's FPGA editor, so you're on your own determining the placement of your flops. I saw a presentation once about a university work group doing TDCs with Altera and ultimately it boiled down to measuring the resolution by using input stimuli to check whether the design was routed according to their wishes. If it was not, they would adjust some timing parameters out of sensible bounds, rinse and repeat.

The last step of course is to sample your signal in the synchronous part of your design (where the counter is) and read the counter plus flip flop contents when the event you wanted occurs (i.e. rising edge, falling edge). Then you have *major* time units in your counter and *minor* time units as a bitfield in the flip flop state.

If you want even spread among your flip flop delays, you will need to carefully examine the delay length of paths between the flip flops and adjust for your overall clock period.

So basically, counter * clock_period + index_of_highest_set_bit_in_flip_flop_state * path_delay is then your delay time.

You will also need to check the FPGA datasheet to know your minimal timings, i.e. the fastest toggle time the input buffer can achieve, the minimal setup and hold time of your flops etc.